# e1 reaction products - cis/trans

Tags: organic-chemistry

The question below ... that goes through an E1 reaction ..

I have came out with the different possible products that can be formed . 
I learnt that E1 reaction forms a cis and a trans product (ignore E,Z,etc for simplicity).

I'm struggling to find which of the products are cis/trans.

Product 2 has obviously no cis/trans. Its between 1 and 2 . Thanks ! [image]

Comment: I'll give you two words: *steric hindrance*. Use it to get the answer.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal *steric hindrance* explains why the reaction may go via E1 - it doesn't rationalise the nature of the product formed. Indeed, E1eliminations show little dependance upon the base used  `The reaction usually occurs in the complete absence of a base or the presence of only a weak base` (Wikipedia).

Comment: @NotEvans I think he's talking about allylic strain, etc. in the product.

Comment: Your issue is that cis- and trans- are better used to describe alkenes that are 1-,2-disubstituted. Otherwise, you should prefer to use (E) and (Z) notation instead.

Answer (score 2):

E-Z notation should be used here. But to answer your question, the longer chain off the double bond takes the priority. In this case, it is the ethyl group. So product 1 is *trans* while product 3 is *cis*.